# SUMPRODUCT with wildcards and NOT statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a working formula that will provide me a count on the basis of explicitly stated search criteria, a fuzzy 'wildcard' based search. It is the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$4:$A$2851=$M8)*(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(N$2,$C$4:$I$2851))*(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L8,$C$4:$I$2851)))))))
```

However, as part of this count I would like to exclude the count from any cells that contain for instance the word 'boost'. To achieve this, in cell J9 I have written *boost* and changed the formula to the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$4:$A$2851=$M9)*(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(N$2,$C$4:$I$2851))*(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L9,$C$4:$I$2851)*(--(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($J9,$C$4:$I$2851)))))))))))`
```

This however has not excluded any matches that also include the term 'boost' in the cell. It simply produces exactly the same count as before.

Could any help possibly be given with this please?

Much appreciated

Comment: You need to explain what the cells `M8` and `L8` are.

Comment: @P.b. - imagine some sort of criteria. number/word/chars etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cell L3 (per screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98CWTszAQhVgqktik?e=4t39ta)) refer:

```
=LET(f,FILTER(C4:I100,A4:A100=M8),SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND(N2,f))*(1-IF(N3="",0,ISNUMBER(FIND(N3,f))))*ISNUMBER(FIND(L8,f))))
```

[image: Screenshot]

*where f in eqn. `Let(f,<>,<>)` denotes the filter function (pre-requisite: Excel as part of Office 365 package)*

Answer (score 0):

In modifying that formula you have mistakenly moved some brackets

Your Formula

[image]

Correct Formula

[image]

That said, several simplifications can be applied

1. Some of those brackets arn't required and can be removed.
2. `NOT(ISNUMBER(...))` can be written `ISERROR(...)`
3. The double negation `--` (used to cast Boolean to Numeric) isn't required, because the `*` does the same job
4. the nesting of the multiplications isn't required

Formula can be reduced to

```
   =SUMPRODUCT(($A$4:$A$2851=$M9)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(N$2,$C$4:$I$2851))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L9,$C$4:$I$2851))*ISERROR(SEARCH($J9,$C$4:$I$2851)))
```